# How do I get SMTP Port 25 to be PCI Compliant on OS X 10.6 Server?

Tags: smtp, mac-osx, pci-dss, osx-snow-leopard

When running PCI security scans on this server it fails on port 25 with:

> SSL Server Supports Weak Encryption
>   nCircle ID: 6174 Port: 25 CVSS Score:
>   5.8 Not Compliant Description The SSL (Secure Socket Layer) Server supports
>   weak encryption keys, which are
>   defined as encryption keys with
>   lengths of less than 128 bits.
>   Messages encrypted with weak
>   encryption keys are relatively easy
>   for an unauthorized user to decrypt.

I have tried modifying /etc/postfix/main.cf with various changes:

- postconf -e smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols="SSLv3,TLSv1"
- postconf -e smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers="high"
- postconf -e smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers="SSLv2,aNULL,ADH,eNULL"

No luck. This is the only port which fails the scan. My web and IMAP pots are all fine.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart or HUP the postfix SMTP process after your configuration changes?

Answer (score 1):

[One document](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Postfix_PCI_Compliance_in_ZCS) I found recommends the following settings for PCI compliance:

```
postconf -e smtpd_tls_ciphers=medium
postconf -e smtpd_tls_protocols=\!SSLv2
postconf -e smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers=high
postconf -e smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers="aNULL, MD5, DES"
```

Then restart the postfix daemon for good measure.
The document is actually for an unrelated VMWare product, but postfix is postfix, right?

;-)